# How to login using microsoft account in react-native

Tags: react-native, azure-ad-msal

I want to log in to my app using a Microsoft account in react native when a "Login with Microsoft" button is clicked.

I had used a component called **react-native-msal** but I am getting errors (as shown in the below image). Can anyone help me on this code or any other component where I can log in using Microsoft account using react native
My code:

```
const config: MSALConfiguration = {
  auth: {
    clientId: (i have written my client id here in my code),
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common'
  
  },

};
const scopes = ['openid', 'profile','user.Read'];
    
 const pca = new PublicClientApplication(config);
console.log(pca);
try {
  await pca.init();
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error initializing the pca, check your config.', error);
}
 const params: MSALInteractiveParams = { scopes };
 const result: MSALResult = await pca.acquireToken(params);
```

Error:

[image: Error i get when i run the above code]

Answer (score 0):

use AzureInstance, AzureLoginView

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74285543/2227743) mean with

> use AzureInstance, AzureLoginView

is probably the views exported by this package:

https://github.com/shedaltd/react-native-azure-ad-2